# Como puedo mostrar datos aleatorios dentro de un loop for

Tags: javascript, jquery

Muy buenas compañeros, tengo tengo este problema, muestro preguntas traídas de un archivo JSON, con las preguntas no tengo problemas, pero con las respuestas necesito mostrar aleatoriamente mostrar de 3 a 8 preguntas cree una función para que me trajera números aleatorios y las utilicé en el for pero no funciono aún me falta aterrizar del todo bien la lógica.

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Este es mi código original donde muestro mis preguntas relacionadas con mis respuestas, pero este ultimo requisito aun no lo cumplo.

```
const preguntas = JSON.parse(data);
const respuestas = JSON.parse(res);

if (preguntas.length !== 0) {
    if (respuestas.length !== 0) {
        for (var w = 0; w < preguntas.length; w++) { //preguntas
            $("#lists").append(
                '<div class="list">' +
                '<ul>' +
                '  <li>' +
                '    <label class="item-checkbox item-content">' +
                '      <input type="checkbox" name="' + preguntas[w].idFinal + '" disabled  checked/>' +
                '      <i class="icon icon-checkbox"></i>' +
                '      <div class="item-inner">' +
                '        <div class="item-title">' + preguntas[w].pregunta + '</div>' +
                '      </div>' +
                '    </label>' +
                '    <div id="respuestasList' + w + '"></div>' +
                '  </li>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</div>'
            );

            for (var r = 0; r < respuestas.length; r++) { //respuestas
                if (preguntas[w].idFinal == respuestas[r].evail_final_id) {
                    $("#respuestasList" + w).append(
                        '<ul>' +
                        '  <li>' +
                        '    <label class="item-checkbox item-content">' +
                        '      <input type="checkbox" onchange="EvaluacionFinal(' + respuestas[r].evail_final_id + ', ' + respuestas.length + ', this, ' + respuestas[w].idRespuestaFinal+')" ' +
                        '        name="' + respuestas[r].evail_final_id + '" value="' + respuestas[r].answer_correct + '"/>' +
                        '      <i class="icon icon-checkbox"></i>' +
                        '      <div class="item-inner">' +
                        '        <div class="item-title">' + respuestas[r].respuesta_final + '</div>' +
                        '      </div>' +
                        '    </label>' +
                        '  </li>' +
                        '</ul>'
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    // falta un }
// falta un }
```

Alguna sugerencia?

La estructura deberia quedar mas o menos asi

JSON de Respuestas

[Preguntas](https://next.json-generator.com/NyOp63m8K)

[JSON  RESPUESTAS](https://next.json-generator.com/VJGKpnXUF)

Comment: He organizado el código un poco mejor y, aunque no creo que sea el problema, faltan dos llaves de cierre al final.

Comment: No me queda claro qué necesitas mostrar aleatoriamente. Todas las respuestas? Solo una? Solo entre 3 y 8 preguntas? Por favor, clarifica qué quieres obtener y muestra un ejemplo del JSON con el que trabajas.

Comment: tengo al menos 78 respuestas en el json, con el if comparo que pertenezcan a la misma pregunta, ahora lo que pretendo es: mostrar aleatoriamente respuestas ligadas a cada una de las preguntas de manera aleatoria siendo que puede a ver o no respuestas correctas. siguiento que : Pregunta 1 - Respuesta 1, Respuesta 2, Respuesta 3 etc.. Pregunta 2 - Respuesta 1, Respuesta 2, Respuesta 3 etc.. si necesitas un ejemplo grafico lo puedo hacer y añado el json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente lo que haces es reordenar las respuestas antes de mostrarlas, en el ejemplo se usa el algoritmo de barajar ( o shuffle ) ["Fisher–Yates Shuffle" en la versión Richard Durstenfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).

Al tener las respuestas ya en orden aleatorio limitas el número a imprimir por cada pregunta.

Es conveniente también armar primero el HTML completo y luego insertarlo donde vaya.

Algo mejor sería ya tener las preguntas y respuestas filtradas desde el backend así nadie hace trampa espiando el source.

```js
// https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
// Mike Bostock
// Fisher–Yates Shuffle versión Richard Durstenfeld
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length,
    t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

// helper marca tareas
const marcarTareaFinalizada = function(numT, msg) {
  let tarea = document.querySelector('#tareasInicio .tarea' + numT)
  if (tarea) {
    tarea.classList.add('finalizada')
    if (typeof undefined !== typeof msg)
      tarea.innerHTML += msg
  }
}

async function cargarCuestionario() {
  const urelePreguntas = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/NyOp63m8K'
  const ureleRespuestas = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/VJGKpnXUF'

  const [preguntasResponse, respuestasResponse] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(urelePreguntas),
    fetch(ureleRespuestas)
  ])
  const lasPreguntas = await preguntasResponse.json()
  marcarTareaFinalizada(1, `<br/> ( ${lasPreguntas.length} )`)

  const lasRespuestas = await respuestasResponse.json()
  marcarTareaFinalizada(2, `<br/> ( ${lasRespuestas.length} )`)

  return {
    lasPreguntas,
    lasRespuestas
  }
}

async function armarCuestionario() {
  const c = await cargarCuestionario().then(
    ({
      lasPreguntas,
      lasRespuestas
    }) => {
      let nP = lasPreguntas.length
      let cuestionario = {
        'info': ` ( p:${nP}, r:${lasRespuestas.length})`,
        'preguntas': []
      }

      while (nP--) { // recorremos preguntas
        cuestionario.preguntas[nP] = lasPreguntas[nP]
        cuestionario.preguntas[nP].respuestas = []
        let nR = lasRespuestas.length
        while (nR--) { // asociamos respuesta ( y la sacamos de las respuestas )
          if (lasPreguntas[nP].idFinal == lasRespuestas[nR].evail_final_id) {
            let laRespuesta = lasRespuestas.splice(nR, 1).shift()
            cuestionario.preguntas[nP].respuestas.push(laRespuesta)
          }
        }
        // aquí podríamos hacer el shuffle, pero lo dejo separado 
        // para no repetir todo el asunto de asociar preguntas y respuestas

        // aquí se podría armar el html 
        // salvo que se quiera shufflear el orden de las preguntas también
      }
      return cuestionario
    })

  marcarTareaFinalizada(3, '<br/>' + c.info)

  let nP, nR, mR
  nP = c.preguntas.length
  while (nP--) { // recorremos preguntas
    // shuffle modifica el array asi que lo clonamos para comparar
    let rRand = shuffle([...c.preguntas[nP].respuestas])
    c.preguntas[nP].respuestasRand = rRand
  }
  marcarTareaFinalizada(4)

  // para limitar el numero de respuestas a mostrar por cada pregunta, definimos un máximo
  // poner un número ridículamente alto para deshabilitar
  mR = 2

  let cuestionarioHTML = '';
  nP = c.preguntas.length
  while (nP--) { // recorremos preguntas
    cuestionarioHTML += '<li class=pregunta>'
    cuestionarioHTML += `<p class=preguntaTitulo>${c.preguntas[nP].pregunta}</p>`

    cuestionarioHTML += '<ul class=respuestas>'
    nR = c.preguntas[nP].respuestas.length
    while (nR--) { // recorremos respuestas
      cuestionarioHTML += `<li class=respuesta>${c.preguntas[nP].respuestas[nR].respuesta_final}</li>`
    }
    cuestionarioHTML += '</ul>'

    cuestionarioHTML += '<ul class=respuestasRand>'

    // aquí elegimos el numero mas pequeño: limite de respuestas o cantidad de respuestas
    nR = Math.min(c.preguntas[nP].respuestasRand.length, mR)
    while (nR--) { // recorremos respuestas
      cuestionarioHTML += `<li class=respuesta>${c.preguntas[nP].respuestasRand[nR].respuesta_final}</li>`
    }
    cuestionarioHTML += '</ul>'
    cuestionarioHTML += '</li>'
  }
  marcarTareaFinalizada(5)

  const cuestionarioDOMel = document.querySelector('#cuestionario')
  cuestionarioDOMel.innerHTML += cuestionarioHTML

  marcarTareaFinalizada(6)
}
armarCuestionario()
```

```css
li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p,
ol,
li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  display: flex
}

#tareasInicio,
.cuestionario {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.cuestionario .pregunta {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #333;
}

.cuestionario .pregunta>.preguntaTitulo {
  width: 20%
}

.cuestionario .pregunta>.respuestas,
.cuestionario .pregunta>.respuestasRand {
  width: 40%
}

.cuestionario .pregunta .respuesta {
  background: #fafafa
}

#tareasInicio,
.cuestionario>li {
  flex-flow: row;
  display: flex
}

.cuestionario,
.cuestionario li>ul {
  flex-flow: column;
  list-style: none
}

#tareasInicio>li {
  background: #f00;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#tareasInicio>li.finalizada {
  background: #0f0
}
```

```html
<ol id=tareasInicio>
  <li class=tarea1>Carga Preguntas</li>
  <li class=tarea2>Carga Respuestas</li>
  <li class=tarea3>Asocia preguntas y respuestas</li>
  <li class=tarea4>Randomiza orden de respuestas</li>
  <li class=tarea5>Arma HTML Cuestionario</li>
  <li class=tarea6>Imprime HTML Cuestionario</li>
</ol>

<ul id=cuestionario class=cuestionario>
  <li class=pregunta>
    <p class=preguntaTitulo>pregunta:</p>
    <ul class=respuestas>
      <li class=respuestaTitulo>respuestas orden json</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class=respuestasRand>
      <li class=respuestaTitulo>respuestas random</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

La función para tener un numero aleatorio entre un mínimo y un máximo, *ambos inclusive*, es:

```javascript
function getRndIntegerInc(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Suponiendo que la propiedad que "enlaza" una respuesta con su pregunta sea `evail_final_id`, yo haría:

```javascript
var html = [];

preguntas.forEach((pregunta, pregunta_idx) => {
    // generas el HTML línea a línea, no lo voy  aponer todo
    html.push('<div class="list">');
    html.push('<ul>');
    html.push('<li>');

    // ...así hasta que tengas que meter las respuestas

    html.push('<div id="respuestasList' + pregunta_idx + '">');

    // nos quedamos únicamente con las repuestas de esta pregunta
    var respuestas = respuestas.filter(function (respuesta) {
        return respuesta.evail_final_id == pregunta.idFinal;
    });

    // elegimos cuántas repuestas queremos
    var num_respuestas = getRndIntegerInc(3, 8);
    
    while (respuestas.length > num_respuestas) {
        // esto elimina un elemento aleatorio del array
        respuestas.splice(getRndIntegerInc(0, respuestas.length - 1), 1);
    }

    // ahora metemos las repuestas
    respuestas.forEach((respuesta, respuesta_idx) => {
        html.push('<ul>');
        html.push('<li>');
        html.push('<label class="item-checkbox item-content">');
        html.push('<input type="checkbox" onchange="EvaluacionFinal(' + respuesta.evail_final_id + ', ' + respuestas.length + ', this, ' + respuesta.idRespuestaFinal+')" name="' + respuesta.evail_final_id + '" value="' + respuesta.answer_correct + '"/>');
        html.push('<i class="icon icon-checkbox"></i>');
        html.push('<div class="item-inner">');
        html.push('<div class="item-title">' + respuesta.respuesta_final + '</div>');
        html.push('</div>');
        html.push('</label>');
        html.push('</li>');
        html.push('</ul>');
    });

    html.push('</div>');

    // y continúas con el código de la pregunta

    html.push('</li>');
    html.push('</ul>');
    html.push('</div>');
});

$("#lists").append(html.join("\n"));
```

Comment: Esta respuesta me ha ayudado, gracias.