# Colores aleatorios de un slider jquery

Tags: jquery, random, slider

```js
var prod_all = $('#container-slider');
var prod = prod_all.find('section');
var number_prod = prod.length;
var slider = $('.slider');

slider.css('width', 100*number_prod/5+'%'); 
prod.css('width', 100/number_prod*5+'%'); 

var s = 0;

function sliders(){
    if(s == 0){
    slider.css('left',0);
    }
    else if(s > 0 ){
    slider.css({'left': '-'+100*s+'%'});
    }   
}

var left_circle = $('#left-circle');
var right_circle = $('#right-circle');

right_circle.add(next).on('click', function(){
    if(s < number_prod - 13){
    s++;
    sliders();
    }
});

left_circle.add(prev).on('click', function(){
    if(s > 0){
        s--;
        sliders();
    }
});
```

```css
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: #f4f4f4;
}
#container-slider{
width: 95%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 1.5%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
.slider{
background: black;
display: flex;
position: relative;
transition: all 2s;
left: 0;
}
.slider section{
height: 300px;
margin: 5px;
}
button{
padding: 0 3%;
line-height: 2;
margin-top: 1.5%;
font-size: 1rem;
cursor: pointer;
}
#next{
float: right;
}
#prev{
float: left;
}
#left-circle,
#right-circle{
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 30;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 3.5vw;
}
#left-circle{
left: 0;
}
#right-circle{
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div id="container-slider">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left" id="left-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right" id="right-circle"></i>
<div class="slider">    
    <section style="background: red;"></section>
    <section style="background: darkblue;"></section>
    <section style="background: darkgreen;"></section>
    <section style="background: darkgray;"></section>
    <section style="background: yellow;"></section>
    <section style="background: skyblue;"></section>
    <section style="background: orange;"></section>
    <section style="background: purple;"></section>
    <section style="background: green;"></section>
    <section style="background: skyblue;"></section>
    <section style="background: green;"></section>
    <section style="background: white;"></section>
    <section style="background: black;"></section>
    <section style="background: blue;"></section>
    <section style="background: brown;"></section>
</div>

<button id="next">Next</button>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>

</div>

<section>
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Exercitationem dolor, labore assumenda expedita sequi, perferendis repudiandae ea accusantium odit quia nemo pariatur? Mollitia quod ab, esse inventore, nulla cumque neque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
```

Hola a todos, tengo este slider que muestra 15 sections de varios colores, necesito ayuda para que de estos 15 section, se muestren sólo 10 aleatoriamente y se oculten los cinco faltantes, he visto en algunos posts que esto es posible con `match.random()`, lo intenté pero sólo llego a mostrar un sólo section `var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * number_prod); prod.hide().eq(random).show(); });`, pero no quiero que me muestre uno sólo, sino los cinco sections que se muestran. Entonces, ¿Cómo hago para mostrar diez section aleatoriamente cada vez que se refresque la página y ocultar los 5 faltantes?, gracias de antemano.

Comment: y si quitas 5 al azar? o es necesario mostrarlos mas tarde?

Comment: si, tambien seria correcto, sólo quiero mostrar de esos 15, diez sections aleatoriamente, pero sólo llego a mostrar uno :'c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ocultamos todos

```
$('#container-slider section').hide();
```

cambiamos el orden a aleatorio

```
$('#container-slider section').shuffle();
```

nos quedamos con los 10 primeros ( removemos lo que sobra a partir de 10 elementos )

```
$('#container-slider section').slice(10).remove();
```

mostramos lo que queda

```
$('#container-slider section').show();
```

La función `shuffle()` no es nativa de jQuery, hay un par de formas de randomizar una lista de elementos la forma considerada menos sesgada ( unbiased ) es la que propone el [algoritmo del sombrero ( "Fisher–Yates Shuffle" )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) del cual hay una implementación vanilla javascript en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/394748/81450), para jQuery transcribo la implementación de [James Padolsey](https://j11y.io/javascript/shuffling-the-dom/) en forma de plugin.

- acomodé un poco el calculo del paginado para tomar el cambio de número de elementos.
- agregué números para identificar los sections

```js
// James Padolsey - Shuffling the DOM
// https://j11y.io/javascript/shuffling-the-dom/

(function($) {

  $.fn.shuffle = function() {

    var allElems = this.get(),
      getRandom = function(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      },
      shuffled = $.map(allElems, function() {
        var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
          randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
        allElems.splice(random, 1);
        return randEl;
      });

    this.each(function(i) {
      $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
    });

    return $(shuffled);

  };

})(jQuery);

$('#container-slider section').hide();
$('#container-slider section').shuffle();
$('#container-slider section').slice(10).remove();
$('#container-slider section').show();

var prod_all = $('#container-slider');
var prod = prod_all.find('section');

var number_prod = prod.length;
var slider = $('.slider');

var prod_porpage = 5;

slider.css('width', 100 * number_prod / prod_porpage + '%');
prod.css('width', 100 / number_prod * prod_porpage + '%');

var s = 0;

function sliders() {
  s = Math.floor(Math.min(Math.max(s, 0), number_prod / prod_porpage - 1))
  if (s == 0) {
    slider.css('left', 0);
  } else if (s > 0) {
    slider.css({
      'left': '-' + 100 * s + '%'
    });
  }
}

var left_circle = $('#left-circle');
var right_circle = $('#right-circle');

right_circle.add(next).on('click', function() {
  s++;
  sliders();
});

left_circle.add(prev).on('click', function() {
  s--;
  sliders();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

#container-slider {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slider {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 2s;
  left: 0;
}

.slider section {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}

button {
  padding: 0 3%;
  line-height: 2;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#next {
  float: right;
}

#prev {
  float: left;
}

#left-circle,
#right-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 30;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
}

#left-circle {
  left: 0;
}

#right-circle {
  right: 0;
}

.slider section {
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px black;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div id="container-slider">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left" id="left-circle"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right" id="right-circle"></i>
  <div class="slider">
    <section style="background: red;">1</section>
    <section style="background: darkblue;">2</section>
    <section style="background: darkgreen;">3</section>
    <section style="background: darkgray;">4</section>
    <section style="background: yellow;">5</section>
    <section style="background: skyblue;">6</section>
    <section style="background: orange;">7</section>
    <section style="background: purple;">8</section>
    <section style="background: green;">9</section>
    <section style="background: skyblue;">10</section>
    <section style="background: green;">11</section>
    <section style="background: white;">12</section>
    <section style="background: black;">13</section>
    <section style="background: blue;">14</section>
    <section style="background: brown;">15</section>
  </div>

  <button id="next">Next</button>
  <button id="prev">Prev</button>

</div>

<section>
  <h2>Titulo</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Exercitationem dolor, labore assumenda expedita sequi, perferendis repudiandae ea accusantium odit quia nemo pariatur? Mollitia quod ab, esse inventore, nulla cumque neque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Recién veo tu comentario, gracias enserio, tendré que practicar esa funcion shuffle, primera vez que la veo, aun estoy en proceso de aprendizaje, gracias !

Answer (score 1):

1.- Lo que podrias hacer es modificar la logica del boton siguiente:

```
right_circle.add(next).on('click', function(){
    if(s < number_prod - 13){
    s++;
    sliders();
    }
});
```

2.- Esta diciendo que si `S`que esta inicializado en `0` es menor que 2 te dejara hacer click en siguiente hasta que `S` sea 2

3.- Si modificas esa logica de la siguiente manera:

```
right_circle.add(next).on('click', function(){
    if(s < number_prod - 14){
    s++;
    sliders();
    }
});
```

3.- Estarás diciendo que si `S` es menor que `1` te deje hacer click, por lo que solo te dejara hacer click 1 vez, y por consecuencia solo te mostrará 10 colores y no 15.

4.- Intentalo y me dices que tal

Comment: Tu respuesta es útil para mostrar sólo 10 sections, pero no resuelve todo el problema, igual gracias por responder